# Nashorn - Optimistic Type filter gets corrupted

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, rhino, nashorn

I am passing primitive objects which are pointed by an Object to the JS side. I am running Nashorn in optimistic mode. I'm using the version 1.8.0.92-b14. The weird thing happens when I return a **boolean** value-at least this is what i noticed while debugging-, from this point on Nashorn engine stops trying to make an optimism to the values. This causes **long** values to be passed as *object* to the js side, however before I return a boolean value, Nashorn was successfully passing the long values as *Number* to the script side.

Below is the object I embedded to the script context.

```
public class TestObject {

    public Object primitivesAsIs(String type) {
    Object result;
    switch (type) {
    case "f":
        result = 15.0f;
        break;
    case "d":
        result = 15.0;
        break;
    case "i":
        result = 1;
        break;
    case "l":
        result = 1L;
        break;
    case "b":
        result = true;
        break;
    case "s":
        result = "hello";
        break;
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is my JS code:

```js
var TYPES = {
    1 : "f",
    2 : "d",
    3 : "i",
    4 : "l",
    5 : "b",
    6 : "s",
};
primitivesAsIs();

function primitivesAsIs() {
    Logger.log("ENTRY primitivesAsIs()");

    //Loop 2 times to see effects on other conversions
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        Logger.log(INFO, "Loop : " + j);
        for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            var result = TestObject.primitivesAsIs(convertToName(i));
            Logger.log("The read value is: " + convertToName(i));
            Logger.log("Typeof : " + typeof result);
        }
    }

    Logger.log("LEAVE primitivesAsIs()");
}

function convertToName(value) {
    var val = TYPES[value];
    return val;
}
```

Nothing special about it but lastly here is my test code:

```
@Test(groups = { "unit" })
public void test()
        throws ScriptException, FileNotFoundException {
    ScriptEngine nashornEngine =
            nashornFactory.getScriptEngine(OPTIMISTIC_TYPES, NO_JAVA, NO_SYNTAX_EXTENSIONS);

    TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
    nashornEngine.put("TestObject", testObject);
    nashornEngine.put("Logger", Logger);

    File file = getFile(JAVA_TO_JS_TYPE_TEST_JS);
    nashornEngine.eval(new FileReader(file));
}
```

**the ouput of the test:**

ENTRY primitivesAsIs()
Loop : 0
The read value is: f
Typeof : number
The read value is: d
Typeof : number
The read value is: i
Typeof : number
**The read value is: l

Typeof : number**
The read value is: b
Typeof : boolean
The read value is: s
Typeof : string
Loop : 1
The read value is: f
Typeof : number
The read value is: d
Typeof : number
The read value is: i
Typeof : number
**The read value is: l

Typeof : object**
The read value is: b
Typeof : boolean
The read value is: s
Typeof : string
LEAVE primitivesAsIs()